# Query Postgis Table with PHP

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, coordinates, php

Would you be so kind as to help me with the following in OpenLayers. I need to be able to use the coordinates from a user click in a postgis query. To catch the coordinates of a click I built a click handler to use the function `map.getLonLatFromViewPort(ext.xy)`, which delivers me the coordinates of my click in the following format: lon = 568417.33622114, lat = 681985.1902844. These are sent to a php-script using a GET request.

I then want to query my postgis db using `ST_GeometryFromText`, which requires that I put my coordinates in the following syntax `((568417.33622114 681985.1902844))`.

Any help on how to get my coordinates in the correct format would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a very basic PHP solution which will convert from your input format to your output format:

```
$coord_array = sscanf($input, "lon = %f, lat = %f");
$x_coord = $coord_array[0];
$y_coord = $coord_array[1];
$output = "((" . $x_coord . " " . $y_coord . "))";
```

Sample data:

```
$input:
lon = 12.34, lat = 56.78
$output:
((12.34 56.78))
```

Answer (score 2):

if you dont want to write your php bridge with postgis, you can use PostGIS to GeoJSON file from postgis_geojson.php [github](https://gist.github.com/1913855) from [Bryan McBride](https://gist.github.com/bmcbride).

```
/**

* PostGIS to GeoJSON

* Query a PostGIS table or view and return the results in GeoJSON format, suitable for
  use in OpenLayers, Leaflet, etc.

*

* @param string $geotable The PostGIS layer name *REQUIRED*

* @param string $geomfield The PostGIS geometry field *REQUIRED*

* @param string $srid The SRID of the returned GeoJSON *OPTIONAL (If omitted, 
         EPSG: 4326 will be used)*

* @param string $fields Fields to be returned *OPTIONAL (If omitted, all fields will 
         be returned)* NOTE- Uppercase field names should be wrapped in double quotes

* @param string $parameters SQL WHERE clause parameters *OPTIONAL*

* @param string $orderby SQL ORDER BY constraint *OPTIONAL*

* @param string $sort SQL ORDER BY sort order (ASC or DESC) *OPTIONAL*

* @param string $limit Limit number of results returned *OPTIONAL*

* @param string $offset Offset used in conjunction with limit *OPTIONAL*

* @return string resulting geojson string

*/
```

i hope it helps you...

Answer (score 2):

```
ST_GeometryFromText( 'POINT($yourlon $yourlat)' )
```

Answer (score 0):

You writing an actionListener to be served with PHP.

First replace the call you using at your client from

```
map.getLonLatFromViewPort(ext.xy)
```

to

```
map.getLonLatFromViewPort(ext.xy).toShortString()
```

Parse the query parameter at server side using the explode function and check them with is_numeric.

You must also pass the map projection code or use a built in constant projection value.
With coordinate and projection code you can create a new point geometry easily with postgis.

Replace the st_geometryfromtext with following:

```
$sql = "SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint( $lng, $lat ), $projCode );";
```

Adjust the query above using your favorite PHP pgsql access library.
I recommend using the new standard PDO class.